# How to send php code info to external link

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using the following code to define certain infos contained in my database data, and send them into an external dynamic page. I am currently able to successfully send 3 of the 4 datas I own.
Post title (1), The plot (2), Poster (3) are sent without any issue; while Snapshot (4) is giving me trouble.

The $send variable is the one that brings data to the external dynamic page. I think I'm doing something wrong in the way I call the 'snapshot' thing in it.

```
$post_title = get_the_title();
$theplot = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'book_plot', true);
$poster_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
$poster_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src($poster_id,'medium', true);

snapshot($post_id) {
global $post;
$thumbnail_ID = get_post_thumbnail_id();
$images = get_children( array('post_parent' => $post_id, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'menu_order ID') );
if ($images) :
foreach ($images as $attachment_id => $image) :
if ( $image->ID != $thumbnail_ID ) :
$img_alt = get_post_meta($attachment_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true); //alt
if ($img_alt == '') : $img_alt = $image->post_title; endif;
$big_array = image_downsize( $image->ID, 'large' );
$img_url = $big_array[0];
echo $img_url;
endif; endforeach; endif; }

$send = 'http://mywebsite.com/show/?title='. urlencode($post_title) . '&plot='. urlencode($theplot) . '&image='. ($poster_src[0]) . '&snapshot='. (snapshot("$post->ID"));
```

Comment: `snapshot($post_id) {` should be `function snapshot($post_id) {` ?

Comment: yeah, but since im not using it in functions.php but in header.php file i tried to remove the 'function' name... Not sure if I made it right...

Comment: @kerbholz .......